# adding an environment variable for NodeJS in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I'm doing some testing on my Vue js application with Nightwatch. Since I have integrated the testing in my gitlab ci/cd I need two different Nightwatch configuration.

In order to achieve that I did the following:

creating two different scripts for local and gitlab test

```
   "scripts" : {
    "e2e" :  "node test/e2e/gitlab_runner.js" ,
    "local-test" :  "node test/e2e/local_runner.js" ,
    "test": "npm run e2e"
```

Then I embed the variable I need in the `local_runner` and `gilab_runner` files

```
process.env.NIGHTWATCH_CONFIG = 'nightwatch.local.js';
require('./runner.js');
```

and for the `gitlab_runner`

```
process.env.NIGHTWATCH_CONFIG = 'nightwatch.conf.js';
require('./runner.js');
```

then in the file `runner.js` I have the following line of code

```
  opts = opts.concat(['--config', 'test/e2e/' + NIGHTWATCH_CONFIG]);
```

So I can get the correct file.

The problem is that when I run the script I get the following error:

```
(node:21061) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: NIGHTWATCH_CONFIG is not defined
    at devConfigPromise.then.then (xxxxxx/test/e2e/runner.js:30:51)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:697:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:516:3)
(node:21061) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:21061) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have also tried to do the following in the `local_runner` and `gitlab_runner` files:

```
  module.exports = {
    NIGHTWATCH_CONFIG = 'nightwatch.local.js';
  };
```

But then the `NIGHTWATCH_CONFIG` variable in the `runner.js` file is undefined.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference error `NIGHTWATCH_CONFIG` is not defined because while calling environment variable `process.env` needs to be specified.

```
opts = opts.concat(['--config', 'test/e2e/' + process.env.NIGHTWATCH_CONFIG]);
```